# Confused by Rxjs Observable constructor and 'this' argument

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm testing use of Rxjs 6.3.3 in a Jasmine test in an Angular 7.2 application. I'm attempting to create an Rxjs Observable but I'm encountering errors that I don't understand.

The function signature of the Rxjs Observable constructor is

```js
constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic);
```

In a Jasmine test I'm trying to instantiate an Observable instance, this requires me to pass a definition of the lambda in the constructor signature. The following syntax:

```js
const obs = new Observable<number>((this: Observable<number>, s: Subscriber<number>): TeardownLogic => {});
```

...fails with

```
"error TS2730: An arrow function cannot have a 'this' parameter."
```

Which I don't understand this because in the constructor's function signature the arrow function definition is declared with a 'this' argument without it being a problem.

This second syntax:

```js
const obs = new Observable((o: Observable<{}>, s: Subscriber<{}>): TeardownLogic => {});
```

...fails with

```
"error TS2345: Argument of type '(o: Observable<number>, s: Subscriber<number>) => TeardownLogic' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable<number>, subscriber: Subscriber<number>) => TeardownLogic'"
```

Which I find confusing because the two function signatures in the error message seem identical to me.

What does work though is simply omitting the first argument altogether like this:

```js
const obs = new Observable((s: Subscriber<{}>): TeardownLogic => {});
```

Which confuses me because now the lambda defined here does not look remotely like the one in the constructor signature.

I'm aware of the use of 'this' in a constructor, and a closure and the different meaning of 'this' in an arrow function. But I'm not aware of any special meaning of 'this' when used as an argument in a method signature. I've Googled around and read the documentation on 'this' in the MDN but am still none the wiser.

In the Observable constructor 'this' in the 'subscribe?: (this: Observable, subscriber: Subscriber) => TeardownLogic' appears to have some kind of magical behaviour. Can anyone explain to me what it is and where I might look to find some documentation about it please?

Comment: Arrow-functions do not have: `this`, and do not have `arguments` and
can’t be called with `new`.

Comment: How about `Observable.create(...)`? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html

Comment: I know I can create an Observable in a variety of other ways, but I want to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In function definition:

```
 (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic
```

Here **this** is a special syntax in Typescript. It specifies the type of the "this" the function expects. So here it just means it should be called by a Observable with the same Type T as the Subscriber.

It comes first in the parameter list. It is a fake parameter, and should invoked without it.

So your code works:

```
new Observable((s: Subscriber<{}>): TeardownLogic => {});
```

I think Typescript just got the type {} and give it to the new Observable, since you did not specify the type. So now they are of the same type.

More info can be found [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions):